# how evalute the expression with or and conditons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

have three quations by checking radio buttons get the values That values I am using in my condition. I tried

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <p>question 1</p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="q1" value="A"><label>Agree</label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="N"><label>Nuetral</label>
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="D"><label>DisAgree</label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="NA"><label>NOt Applicable</label></p>
            <p>question 2</p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="q2" value="A"><label>Agree</label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="N"><label>Nuetral</label>
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="D"><label>DisAgree</label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="NA"><label>NOt Applicable</label></p>
            <p>question 3</p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="q3" value="A"><label>Agree</label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="N"><label>Nuetral</label>
            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="D"><label>DisAgree</label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="NA"><label>NOt Applicable</label></p>
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var A = 10, N = 6, D = 3, NA = 0;
                var v1, v2, v3;
                $("#submit").click(function(){debugger;
                var q1 = $('input[name=q1]:checked').val();
                var q2 = $('input[name=q2]:checked').val();
                var q3 = $('input[name=q3]:checked').val();     
                 toString1(q1v, q2v, q3v);              
                    if((q1 == "A" || q1 == "N") && ((q1+q2+q3)/3 > 0.60)){
                     console("q1 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60%");
                    }
                    else if((q2 == "A" || q2 =="N") && ((q1+q1+q1/3) > 0.60)){
                     console("q2 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60% ");
                    }
                    else if((q3 == "A" || q3 == "N") && ((q1+q1+q1/3) > 0.60)){
                     console("q3 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60% ");
                    }
                    else{
                        console("q1,q2 and q3 DisAgree or NotApplicable and also value is bellow 60% ");
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you edit the code so it displays correctly and reformulate the question as it's not clear what you want? Posting an example of the expected outcome would also help.

Comment: i added code in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3o6am8f3/5/ please check once

Comment: ...and the expected result? What should happen in either case?

Comment: q1 contian "A" value means A = 10 q2 containt "N" means N= 6 then when i am adding q1+q2+q3

Comment: q1 coming string value "A" , how to convert String to variable like A and q2 coming string value "N" how to convert String to variable like N bcz i declared A =10 and N=6

Comment: please help me any one

Comment: if you want to check with console write console.log I think you know this right ?

Comment: And https://jsfiddle.net/3o6am8f3/8/ check this

Answer (score 1):

You can start by declaring an object with the key being the code you're retrieving from your form and the value being the numerical value, as such:

```
var values = {
  'A': 10,
  'N': 6,
  'D': 3,
  'NA': 0
}
```

Now you can access your values as `values[q1]` where `q1` is one of A, N, D or NA. Here's a working example:

```js
$(function () {
  var values = {
    'A': 10,
    'N': 6,
    'D': 3,
    'NA': 0
  }

  $('#submit').on('click', function () {
    var q1 = $('input[name=q1]:checked').val()
    var q2 = $('input[name=q2]:checked').val()
    var q3 = $('input[name=q3]:checked').val()

    console.log('Value for q1: ' + values[q1])
    console.log('Value for q2: ' + values[q2])
    console.log('Value for q3: ' + values[q3])

    var sum = values[q1] + values[q2] + values[q3]

    console.log(sum)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <p>question 1</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="q1" value="A"><label>Agree</label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="N"><label>Nuetral</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="D"><label>DisAgree</label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="NA"><label>NOt Applicable</label></p>
    <p>question 2</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="q2" value="A"><label>Agree</label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="N"><label>Nuetral</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="D"><label>DisAgree</label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="NA"><label>NOt Applicable</label></p>
    <p>question 3</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="q3" value="A"><label>Agree</label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="N"><label>Nuetral</label>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" value="D"><label>DisAgree</label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="NA"><label>NOt Applicable</label></p>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PS: try viewing the snippet in full screen